# Redux-toolkit: Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers

Tags: react-redux

hi I am getting an error about redux-toolkit.I don't know why it is showing me error and I have uploaded

full error:
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  users: userReduce
});
```

https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers